# Flask-WhooshAlchemy: Searching for 'not'

Tags: python, flask, full-text-search, whoosh

I just got through the Flask mega-tutorial's section on implementing full text search with Flask-WhooshAlchemy (http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-full-text-search) and I have the posts below:

```
>>> Post.query.whoosh_search('fourth').all()
[Post u'not my fourth', Post u'my fourth and last post']
```

I tried using `Post.query.whoosh_search('fourth AND not').all()` expecting to get back `[Post u'not my fourth']` as a result but I'm getting both of the original posts instead.

How do I get WhooshAlchemy to treat the `not` as a string rather than an operator?

Answer (score 0):

According to the last paragraph on this page in the [Flask-WhooshAlchemy docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/), query terms are treated like an AND by default. So change your search to be

```
Post.query.whoosh_search("fourth not").all()
```

If you are still having issues with it, perhaps you have to do

```
Post.query.whoosh_search("fourth AND 'not'").all()
```

as per [Whoosh's docs on making a term from literal text](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/querylang.html).

Comment: Both `Post.query.whoosh_search("fourth not").all()` and `Post.query.whoosh_search("fourth AND 'not'").all()` return both of the posts. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could it be the `.all()`? If you omit that, do you get a query or whoosh object back, or the results you need?

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your setup.

```
>>> Post.query.whoosh_search('fourth not').all()
>>> [<Post u'not my fourth'>, <Post u'my fourth and last post'>]
```

The question you should have asked is: Why can't whoosh_search find not?  Try this.

```
>>> Post.query.whoosh_search('not').all()
>>> []
```

This should have returned the post 'not my fourth', right?

According to the "Stop Words" section in [this document](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/analysis.html), “Stop” words are words that are so common it’s often counter-productive to index them.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087290/python-whoosh-seems-to-return-incorrect-results) has a link which shows that by default 'not' is a stop word, and whoosh_search does not index it.

So lets add another post with 'fourth' and a less common word - how about 'cheese'.

```
>>> p = Post(body='cheese is the fourth food group', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), author=u)
>>> db.session.add(p)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

And now lets search for all posts with 'fourth' AND 'cheese' in the body.

```
>>> Post.query.whoosh_search('fourth cheese').all()
>>> [<Post u'cheese is the fourth food group'>]
```

Perfect.

BONUS: if you want to get all posts with 'fourth' OR 'cheese', do this:

```
>>> Post.query.whoosh_search('cheese fourth', or_=True).all()
>>> [<Post u'cheese is the fourth food group'>, <Post u'not my fourth'>, <Post u'my fourth and last post'>]
```